# Where is the "scribus1xx.rc" file on macOS?

Tags: scribus

I'm trying to follow [this page](https://wiki.scribus.net/canvas/How_to_create_spot_colour_sets_from_scratch) from the scribus wiki. I'm using scribus 1.4.7 on macOS 10.13. But I don't find the `*.rc` file. As macOS is a *nix-like system, I do expect it in `~/.scribus/`, but there is no such folder.

Comment: The dot (.) at the beginning of the name would indicate it's a **hidden** directory on a Mac. You'll need something which shows hidden directories or use the Go To item in the Finder Menus.

Comment: @Scott: I used Terminal (not Finder) and `ls -all` shows hidden folders.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On macOS, the preferences are in

`~/Library/Preferences/Scribus/`

`~` is your Home directory, typically: `/Users/Your-name`

In the Finder, you can open *your* Library directory by holding down the "option" while the "Go" menu: among other "places", it will show your “Library” directory.

OS X is a bit of a Unix... but you know, even on Linux, nowadays the preferences are in `.config/scribus/`...

Comment: Tobi, since you edited my answer and accepted it, I believe that, now, the path is correct : - ) ... i don't have a Mac for checking...